# html making an email fit across multiple mobile devices

Tags: html

hi i'm creating an enewsletter and am trying to resize it for when its viewd on a mobile i have it working on iphone but android i'm unsure as to how to resize because of the massive screen variants. heres what ive got so far.

so in my  i have too added things that overide the style if the screen width is a certain size.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
            .hide { display: none !important; }
            #main_content, #inner_content, .mobwidth { width: 300px !important; }
            #content_rows, .mobwidthtext {width:300px !important;}
            .banner {height:94px !important;}
            .top {height:67px !important;}  
            .footer {height:109px !important;}

    }


    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 400px) {
            .hide { display: none !important; }
            #main_content, #inner_content, .mobwidth { width: 400px !important; }
            #content_rows, .mobwidthtext {width:380px !important;}
            .banner {height:117px !important;}
            .top {height:83px !important;}  
            .footer {height:136px !important;}

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most email clients ignore CSS declarations that are not inline. Embedded stylesheets are ignored as well. Media queries will not work because they would override those made by web-based email clients, such as Gmail (i.e. what you want to do will not work).

Email HTML standards are pretty brain-dead. Keep in mind that things like MS Outlook don't even use browser technology to view emails - they use the MS Word engine.

Here's a good guide as to what CSS features can be used in emails:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: +1 was just about to link the very same site .. invaluable resource

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the above answer. Using media queries for mobile will most definitely work but for android set your max screen size to 480. make sure to keep !important on all styles set by the query and ensure you have a general layout in your inline styles. this will result in browser stripping the css in head and just using the inline. Then the mobiles (majority of which do not strip head) using your media queries, I would recommend a large amount of testing before a send. But the only issue you have atm is just finding the correct maxwidths as you have to take into account the portrait and landscape widths as well. While also considering that zoom can also set off meia Queries with some devices